# How can i find the City name using IP address in Java

Tags: java, location, ip

I want city name from IP address using Java

is there any idea to do this ?

Comment: This has been asked a lot.  Please try searching before posting.

Comment: This is not programming related... No language can help you with that, you can query a datasource to get this information and this can be a website, a database, an xml service etc...

Comment: @Numenor: this is definitely, completely, utterly and totally programming related. Your comment overall doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: imagine this "i want city names of countries using Java" is this about programming? NO, its about querying the data source you have available to get this information. Tushar here is asking where he can get the data to get information on IP addresses, not how to code that programmatically, and his answer is provided by ANdrey and its a url.....

Comment: @Numenor: Andrey and medopal 's answers are constructive.  Yours it not.  Who exactly is going to use the URL provided by Andrey in the way medopal showed it?  Butchers?  Doctors?  Nurses?  You, sir Numenor, are seriously unwell and haven't quite understood yet how SO works.  Wanting to find a city name using an IP address from Java *is a programming related question*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Andrey link, here is how to construct the inquiry, this code will return an HTML file with all details of current IP, including city;

```
String IP= "123.123.123.123";
URL link = new URL("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress="+IP);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
     System.out.println(inputLine);             
}

in.close();
```

**UPDATE, 23 May 2013**

The previous answer is ok, but it's not an API call, it reads an HTML page, that I provided previously because I didn't find any free APIs. Next is a REST API call that can be used easily and will return all the info required, it's recommended to use this one:

```
String ip = "2.51.255.200"; 
URL url = new URL("http://freegeoip.net/csv/" + ip);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

int status = connection.getResponseCode();
if (status != 200) {
    return null;
}

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    //this API call will return something like:
    "2.51.255.200","AE","United Arab Emirates","03","Dubai","Dubai","","x-coord","y-coord","",""
    // you can extract whatever you want from it
}
```

Comment: Update 2020? freegeoip is down, I am using https://ipstack.com/ which offers free and paid subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If your Application is deployed behind the firewall. So instead of calling a API, we can use GeoLite below is the sample code.

Download City.dat file from http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

```
            File    datapath = new File("GeoLiteCity.dat");
            LookupService cl = new LookupService(datapath,
                    LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE
                            | LookupService.GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE);
            String cityName = cl.getLocation(ipAddress).city;
```